# JButton covers other buttons

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jbutton

I have been stuck in this for a while. The problem is that I want to shift my button to the right side of my screen, but when I use borderlayout.east it removes the other button that I created. Can anyone explain why it does so, and how do I fix this problem?

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        GUI();

    }


    public static void GUI(){

        handle handle = new handle();
        JButton buy[] = new JButton[8];


        _panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        for(int i = 0; i < buy.length; i++){

            buy[i] = new JButton("Buy");
            _panel.add(buy[i],BorderLayout.EAST);

        }


        _panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));        

        //_panel.add(buy, BorderLayout.EAST);

        _frame.add(_panel);
        _frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        _frame.setLocation(500, 100);
        _frame.setResizable(false);
        _frame.getContentPane();
        _frame.pack();
        _frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: You are adding all button at the same region i.e.`BorderLayout.EAST`, instead you may possibly use [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Comment: I have read through BoxLayout, BorderLayout and bag....but none of them work the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [#JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html).

> **BORDER LAYOUT**
>
> A border layout lays out a container, arranging and resizing its
>   components to fit in five regions: north, south, east, west, and
>   center. **Each region may contain no more than one component**, and is
>   identified by a corresponding constant: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, and
>   CENTER.

---

You are adding all `JButtons` to east of `JPanel`.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < buy.length; i++){
        buy[i] = new JButton("Buy");
        _panel.add(buy[i],BorderLayout.EAST);<-------------
    }
```

*So last one only gets visible at east.*

---

*So how should I fix it?*

- Put all buttons to `JPanel` (say with `GridLayout`) and add that `JPanel` to `East` of the `JFrame` or other `JPanel`.

  ***FOR EXAMPLE***

  ```
  JPanel myPanel=new JPanel();
  myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(Button_array.length-1,1))
  for(int i = 0; i < buy.length; i++){
      buy[i] = new JButton("Buy");
      _myPanel.add(buy[i]);
  }
  _panel.add(myPanel,BorderLayout.EAST)
  ```

Comment: So how should I fix it? am I able to resize the button or shift it?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the layout replaces the other content, you will probably want to add a Panel to the east and then append buttons to that, something like this:

```
    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    _panel.add(supPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    for(int i = 0; i < buy.length; i++){

        buy[i] = new JButton("Buy");
        subPanel.add(buy[i]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the General Layout:

[image: General Layout]

Check [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/how-to-add-jtable-in-jpanel/5630271#5630271) for more information.